# Boost linking warning

Tags: c++, linux, boost, linker, g++

What happened:

1. I built boost with bootstrap.sh and b2. Installed with ./b2 install
2. Couldn't figure out how to use it, as I'm a newbie
3. sudo apt install libboost-dev
4. Searched online for instructions. I can now link it with no errors
5. sudo apt purge libboost-dev
6. There's a warning: "/usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_system.so.1.58.0, needed by //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmirclient.so.9, may conflict with libboost_system.so.1.66.0"
7. I'm using boost 1.66. The .a and .so files are in /usr/local/lib
8. There are some boost 1.58 .a and .so files in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
9. If I use /usr/local/lib/[library] instead of -L/usr/local/lib/ -l[libraries-without-.a] the warning disappears. However, the Makefile gets significantly longer.

My questions: Is the warning serious? How can I get rid of it? How can I use -L command without triggering that warning? Can I delete the boost .a and .so files in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu? I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 by the way.

Thanks.